# Nested For Loop dealing with one collection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a collection of data, and am trying to work with it, and remove items as necessary. Below is my code, and please tell if it is possible to loop through the same collection multiple times at the same time..

I save the first item to a variable, in order to use as reference when searching through the collection. If there is a match then the counter increases, and when the counter is 2 and above I then search the collection to remove the same item from the entire collection. I think the way I have written the code is self explanatory with what I am trying to achieve. If items exist more than once in the collection they need to be removed.

I am getting a runtime error '9' where is set:

```
tempStorageB = EScoll(j)
```

I am unsure as to why this is occurring so any guidance/ help is appreciated!

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, k as Long 

Dim EScoll As New Collection

Dim tempStorageA as Variant
Dim tempStorageB as Variant
Dim tempStorageC as Variant

Dim counter as Integer



For i = 1 To EScoll.Count
    tempStorageA = EScoll(i)

    'counter loop
    For j = 1 To EScoll.Count
        tempStorageB = EScoll(j)
        If tempStorageB = tempStorageA Then
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter >= 2 Then

                'remove all duplicates from collection loop
                For k = EScoll.Count To 1 Step -1
                    tempStorageC = EScoll(k)
                    If tempStorageC = tempStorageA Then
                        EScoll.Remove k
                    End If
                Next k

            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To EScoll.Count
    Debug.Print EScoll(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Where is  EScoll defined?

Comment: @QHarr, EScoll is defined in the same procedure. I have edited my post to show this.

Comment: it's probably because you create your loop j based on the count of objects at that time, then you remove and item in the k loop, and suddenly the count has changed but j will still try to loop up to what the previous total count was

Comment: What's the value of `j` when the error occurs? Looking at the code, the remove duplicates looks like it would remove `all` instances, not `all - 1` (unless I'm mis-reading the code). This would result in only values which were originally unique. Everything which originally had a count of > 1, which be completely removed.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Isn't that why there's a `Step -1`? So that `k` starts at the max value, then decreases down to 1?

Comment: I assume that you're not showing where `EScoll` is being populated. The code as shown is using the collection without filling it. Also, you may be better served to use a `Dictionary` when creating the dataset, because you could use the `Exists` property to prevent duplicates in the first place.

Comment: I created the k loop to loop backwards so that when an item is removed the collection is reinitialised and the i and j loop should count forwards meeting the total of the collection after the deleted items. The whole point is to remove all non unique items from the collection.

Comment: @PeterT the collection is populated in the same sub procedure, but I did not add it to my post because it is irrelevant to the error.

Comment: Here's the scenario I'm imagining: there are 3 items in the list. when it loops for j, it is set that it will loop 3 times. In one of j's loops, the k loop deletes an item from the list. Now there are 2 items in the list, but j will still try to access a 3rd item causing the `subscript out of range` error he's receiving.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I think you may be right with your first comment. j = 573 when the error gets thrown. I think because I am setting the loop based on the initial count. I assumed that the .Count would update as .Remove is used? If this is not the case, can you think of a solution to that?

Comment: @D.DeVilliers I don't see how you're 'reinitialising' the collection in k once you remove an item. At that point, the number of times that i and j will loop has already been set and can't be changed.

Comment: If you insist on using a `Collection`, then your best bet to delete something is to set up quick `Sub` to delete only one item from the collection at a time, then move on to find another duplicate until they are all eliminated.

Comment: @D.DeVilliers unfortunately it does not update dynamically. I think it probably requires a different approach. I would be surprised to learn there is not already a function out there to check for vba collection duplicates, but you could also try the dictionary method that PeterT mentioned

Comment: Populate your collection without duplicates, you can use the key for this purpose

Comment: @PeterT would running through another sub help? Meaning if the collection is being looped through and an item is removed via another sub, then isn't the same error going to occur where the count exceeds the number of items in the collection?

Comment: @EvR if I populate without duplicates then I still have the same items of the duplicates. The point is to not have any item in the collection that reflects a duplicate

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 do you not think there is a way to have an integer say `collectionCount` and for example have `For i = 1 to collectionCount ... For j = 1 to collectionCount... For k = collectionCount to 1 step -1` and when `.Remove` is used update `collectionCount = EScoll.Count` ?

Comment: @D.DeVilliers vba is a cruel mistress and does not let you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show the solution (for future reference for anyone who has a similar problem) I have come up with the new understanding of the cause of the initial error. The problem being that once setting the count of the for loop to the count of the collection it would not change after an item was deleted. A simple and effective solution for me was to loop through in a similar fashion as above, however, instead of using .Remove I added all the values that were unique to a new collection. See below:

```
Dim SPcoll As New Collection

For i = 1 To EScoll.Count
    tempStorageA = EScoll(i)
    counter = 0
    For j = 1 To EScoll.Count
        tempStorageB = EScoll(j)

        If tempStorageB = tempStorageA Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

    Next j

    If counter < 2 Then

    SPcoll.Add tempStorageA

    End If
Next i
```

`SPcoll` now contains all unique items from previous collection!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will remove duplicates from a `Collection`.

Because of the iterative nature of the search, you have to search and remove one at a time. While this is rather inefficient, the `Collection` object does not lend itself to being efficient for these operations.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Dim EScoll As New Collection
    PopulateCollection EScoll

    Dim duplicatesFound As Boolean
    Do
        duplicatesFound = False
        Dim checkItem As Long
        For checkItem = 1 To EScoll.Count
            Dim dupIndex As Long
            dupIndex = DuplicateItemExists(EScoll, EScoll.Item(checkItem))
            If dupIndex > 0 Then
                duplicatesFound = True
                EScoll.Remove (dupIndex)
                '--- kick out of this loop and start again
                Exit For
            End If
        Next checkItem
    Loop Until Not duplicatesFound
    Debug.Print "dupes removed, count = " & EScoll.Count
End Sub

Function DuplicateItemExists(ByRef thisCollection As Collection, _
                             ByVal thisValue As Variant) As Long
    '--- checks to see if two items have the same given value
    '    RETURNS the duplicate index number
    Dim valueCount As Long
    valueCount = 0
    Dim i As Long
    DuplicateItemExists = 0
    For i = 1 To thisCollection.Count
        If thisCollection.Item(i) = thisValue Then
            valueCount = valueCount + 1
            If valueCount > 1 Then
                DuplicateItemExists = i
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Sub PopulateCollection(ByRef thisCollection As Collection)
    Const MAX_ITEMS As Long = 50
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To MAX_ITEMS
        thisCollection.Add CLng(Rnd(10) * 10)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your populating is in same sub, I would delete your duplicates during (just after)
adding)

```
Sub tsttt()

Dim EScoll As New Collection
Dim DoublesColl As New Collection
Dim x

With EScoll
    For Each x In Range("a1:a10").Value 'adjust to your data
        On Error Resume Next
        .Add x, Format(x)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            DoublesColl.Add x, Format(x)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next
    For Each x In DoublesColl
        .Remove Format(x)
    Next
 End With

End Sub
```